# CSV parser not getting rows from file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam parsing a CSV and have the following line that gets the csv lines by splitting the whole file using a newline character.

```
csvLines = e.target.result.split("\n");
```

I generated a CSV from excel on a Mac and tried to read it, but iam getting everything in one line as if there is no newline character.

I opened the csv in my text editor and i can see everything is in a separate line.But in my code i just get one row with all the data.

Comment: What is the encoding of your file? I usually check the encoding with Notepad++ or SublimeText.

Comment: an online tool is detecting (ASCII)...could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your file probably uses carriage return ("\r") instead of line feed ("\n") as row delimiter. So try "\r" instead of "\n" in your code.